# 2 docker containers run in 1 container

Tags: docker, linux-containers

i try to start two detached containers.

first a MySql

```
docker run -td --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_PASS="admin" tutum/mysql
```

the i try to start a self built container for apache, typo3

```
docker run -td --name typo -p 80:80 --link mysql:mysql thomasm/typo3-45
```

i would now expect that the two containers show up in docker ps

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
96607b9ee0f9        tutum/mysql:latest   "/run.sh"           19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   mysql,typo/mysql
```

but both seem to be in this one container id (watch the NAMES column).

docker ps -a now shows that the "typo" container has exited

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                    NAMES
4d5ab7351d49        thomasm/typo3-45:latest         "/start.sh"            8 minutes ago       Exited (0) 8 minutes ago                                 typo
```

I'm a bit confused. Why does the typo name show up in the names column of the mysql container. And why does the typo container exit? I don't see any error messages. Non detached, with bash the typo container works...

output from docker logs

```
$ docker logs typo 
* Starting web server apache2                                                  
AH00558:      apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.16. 
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

*

Comment: Can you edit your question adding the result of the `docker logs typo` command?

Comment: "Why does the typo container exist?" Because you started it!?! It exited withouth errors, hence the status reads: "Exited (0) 8 minutes ago"

Comment: i wrote "exit" not "exist". i added docker logs typo output.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I recommend not starting a container with -d until you have such issues resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the typo name show up in the names column of the mysql container

because they are linked together

> why does the typo container exit?

You might find clues by running `docker logs typo`. A common mistake is to have the container run the process in the background instead of in the foreground.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "run the process in the background instead of the foreground"? Apache is always running in background, isn't it?

Comment: ok, got what you mean. starting apache now with apachectl -DFOREGROUND